# Use PowerShell locally to get Azure DevOps last build id on branch

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

For development purpose we need to have a PowerShell script launched locally via Visual Studio which task is to get the last build id of a specific branch.

So far I have tried many options based on this:

```
$WebClient = New-Object Net.WebClient
Write-Host "Downloading patches and binaries"

Write-Host "Get ID"

$url = "https://oldrepo.visualstudio.com/ProjectA/_apis/build/latest/14?branchName=master"
$result = $WebClient.DownloadString($url)

Write-Host $result
```

However the `result` value returns the login page of azure and not my repository. If I paste the same url in a browser however I do get the good page.

I suppose that there's some sort of cookie / AD credentials passed through the request but I haven't seen anything relevant via developer tools.

I tried to manually set credentials to the WebClient object like this:

```
#$creds = Get-Credential -UserName "User" -Message "Login"
#$WebClient.Credentials = $creds
#$WebClient.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
```

But to no avail. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use `Invoke-RestMethod` to get Azure DevOps Rest API response, and you need to authenticate with [Personal Access Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate):

```
$token = "YOUR-PAT" 
$base64Auth = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "",$token))) 
$header = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64Auth)} 
$url = "https://oldrepo.visualstudio.com/ProjectA/_apis/build/latest/14?branchName=master" 
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Headers $header
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. In case someone is struggling with the code: There are some minor typos in there, this is how it is running:

`$token = "YOUR-PAT"`
`$base64Auth = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "",$token)))`
`$header = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64Auth)}`
`$url = "https://oldrepo.visualstudio.com/ProjectA/_apis/build/latest/14?branchName=master"`
`$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Headers $header`

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, it seems to be impossible to use multiline code in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Shayki's answer works but the latest API endpoints have changed  more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/latest/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)

and please find the updated query below

```
$token = "YOUR-PAT"     
$base64Auth = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "",$token)))
    $header = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64Auth)} 
    $url = "GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/latest/{definition}?api-version=7.0-preview.1" 
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Headers $header 
    $result.id
```